# C - Appending to string - Possible memory errors

Tags: c, string, memory-management

I am trying to a create a function that keeps on appending a string to a char variable. However, some times it works and other times it doesn't. I am wondering where the bug is?

```
char *final_output = NULL;
void add_string(const char *);

int main(void) {
    add_string("Hello world\n");
    add_string("This is my new function!\n");

    /* Let's print */
    while (final_output && *final_output) {
        printf("%c", *final_output);
        *final_output++;
    }
}

void add_string(const char *text) {
    if (final_output == NULL) {
        final_output = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
    }
    else {
        final_output = (char *) realloc(final_output, strlen(final_output) + strlen(text) + 2);
    }

    strncat(final_output, text, strlen(text));
}
```

Comment: It's redundant to use `strncat()` when the length is `strlen(text)`, since that's exactly what `strcat()` does without having to read the string twice.

Comment: The +2 is equally redundant. you only need +1 for the sole terminator the resulting string will house. And I hope you realize you just lost your only pointer to the string as soon as you walk to the terminator in your output loop. (iow, how are you planning on freeing that thing?). Finally, stop casting allocation functions in C. [No good can come of it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: What does it do when it doesn't work? I wasn't able to get it to fail.

Comment: Your `while` loop is is equivalent to `printf("%s", final_output)`, and that doesn't have the problem that @WhozCraig points out.

Comment: As long as were on the subject of questionable code, `*final_output++;` results in a harmless (losing the pointer you need to free not withstanding), but none-the-less meaningless dereference. The pointer is incremented, but the dereference is worthless.

Comment: Thanks for all your help guys. I made the necessary modifications as suggested by you guys. I didn't realise losing the head of a string meant I was causing memory leaks as well. In that case, what is the best way to loop through a pointer and still retain the memory address for freeing?

Comment: [Something like this springs to mind](http://ideone.com/6eAk0S). Note: not checked beyond making sure it compiles).

Comment: this line:  is in error.  It looses the pointer to the allocated memory.  Also, the allocated memory is not being free'd resulting in a resource loss.

Comment: the code block, beginning with: while (final_output && *final_output) { does not work correctly.  suggest replacing the code block with a simple: printf("%s\n", final_output );

Comment: the function realloc() can be used with a pointer to null, so there is no need to have the if/else sequence, just the line with the realloc statement.

Comment: Using realloc on its own produces segmentation fault if the pointer is null. Don't know why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in function `add_string`. You do not append the allocated or copied array with the terminating zero after statements

```
final_output = malloc(strlen(text) + 1);
```

and

```
strncat(final_output, text, strlen(text));
```

Rewrite the function the following way

```
void add_string( const char *s ) 
{
    if ( final_output == NULL ) 
    {
        final_output = malloc( strlen( s ) + 1 );
        final_output[0] = '\0';
    }
    else 
    {
        final_output = realloc( final_output, strlen( final_output ) + strlen( s ) + 1 );
    }

    strcat( final_output, s );
}
```

Comment: Beautiful buddy! Solves all of my problems!! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Vlad, I had one more question: suppose I have a variable called int i = 123. If I want to pass this i directly, like add_string(i), what should I do? Thanks!

Comment: @antikbd You can use for example function sprintf